# завершить второй поток с бесконечным циклом

Tags: c++, qt

Создал второй поток с бесконечным циклом:

```
sensormanager = new(SensorManager);
pThread = new(QThread);
sensormanager->moveToThread(pThread);
QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), sensormanager, SLOT(slotAutoModeBalancer()));
QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(finished()), sensormanager, SLOT(quit()));
pThread->start();
```

Где

```
slotAutoModeBalancer() {

     runFlag = true;
     while(runFlag) {
     for(int i = 0; i < numberBalanser; i++)
     {
         unsigned short int buf[2];
         buf[0] = 0;
         buf[1] = 0;
         sensorinfo->readVoltageBatteryAndTemperatureBalancer((i+1),buf);
         Balanser[i].Voltage = buf[0];
         Balanser[i].Index   = i+1;
         Balanser[i].Temperature = buf[1];
     }
     qsort(Balanser,numberBalanser,sizeof(Balanser[0]),cmp);
     int rc_1 = 0;
     int rc_2 = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < numberBalanser;  i++)
     {
         if( ( Balanser[numberBalanser -1 - i].Voltage - Balanser[i].Voltage ) > 
     MaxHysteresis)
         {
             rc_1 = sensorinfo->writeStartChargeBalancer(Balanser[i].Index);
             rc_2 = sensorinfo->writeStartDischargeBalancer(Balanser[numberBalanser -1 - i].Index);
             Balanser[i].modeWork = ChargeBalancer;
             Balanser[numberBalanser -1 - i].modeWork = DischargeBalancer;

             qDebug()<<"Charge = " << Balanser[i].Index << rc_1 << "Discharge = "<< 
             Balanser[numberBalanser -1 - i].Index << rc_2 ;
         }
     }
     QThread4xx::msleep(5000);
}
```

Как можно остановить цикл while и выполнить команду аварийной остановки? Версия qt4.7.8.

Comment: `runFlag = false`, очевидно... подразумевая, что это атомарный тип...

Comment: Я это понимаю. runFlag = false выполнится только тогда когда  while выполнит все свое тело цикла. А это почти 7 секунд. А нужно остановить мгновенно.

Comment: Терминируйте его QThread::terminate() , но гарантии мгновенного выпиливания нет. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, плохой совет... смотри warning по своей ссылке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Согласен, а какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: @zhilenkov, добавь объявления используемых классов/структур/функций и порядки чисел в циклах... а ещё лучше если это будет полноценный [mcve]... без этого сложно дать адекватный совет... вообще говоря, основные тезисы такие: использовать флаг — правильная идея; «остановить мгновенно» — где-то между невозможно, опасно и очень дорого, но можно свести время к разумному минимуму...

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, ^

Comment: можно грубо расставить проверки на `runFlag` внутри циклов for, тогда не придется ждать одного прохода балансировщика. немного неэстетично, зато дешево, надежно и практично.

Comment: а вообще я бы сделал по-другому - в классе воркера завел бы таймер, который с нужным вам интервалом вызывал бы метод балансировщика, это более феншуйный метод в частности и в вопросе остановки, в вашем случае по-любому придется ждать, пока отработает sleep